# Procedure for traveling to the US on a green card

Tags: air-travel, usa, customs-and-immigration

I have a Green Card. Years ago I traveled to the US without a Green Card and one had to fill out something online 24 hours before traveling. Does this apply to Green Card holders?

Are there any specific procedures for traveling to the US on a Green Card?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to fill out is a customs form. Also, be sure to present your passport in addition to the green card at the immigration checkpoint.

> If seeking to enter the United States after temporary travel abroad,
>   you will need to present a valid, unexpired “green card” (Form I-551,
>   Permanent Resident Card). When arriving at a port of entry, a U.S.
>   Customs and Border Protection Officer will review your permanent
>   resident card and any other identity documents you present, such as
>   **a passport, foreign national I.D. card or U.S. Driver’s License**, and determine if you can enter the United States.  ([Link](http://www.uscis.gov/green-card/after-green-card-granted/international-travel-permanent-resident))

Comment: Permanent residents can enter the US with only a green card; no passport is needed.  Is there a benefit to presenting the foreign passport at immigration?

Comment: @phoog: see my edit above. Anecdotally, whenever I have entered the U.S. with my green card, I've been always asked to present my passport.

Comment: @Macondo2Seattle: phoog is right. Technically, a passport is not required for a returning LPR with a green card. However, most people have it, and it may be beneficial to present a passport so that it can get stamped.